# Breeze - Add/create partial entity to metadata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm trying to add a partial object to the breeze entity manager/metadata.

This is the scenario:
I'm selecting two properties via breeze "Linq" style. Fiddler returns exactly the properties I'm asking for. So all good! Further I'm using breeze to create models from metadata. If i want the full entity (all properties) it's working like a charm.

Now i want to create a partial object (only the rows i selecting + one custom property).

I would like to register the partial object in breeze because of the nice usage of caching.

/J

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in two steps:

- 1) Create a new EntityType that matches your partial object shape and add it to the metadataStore with your own custom type name.
- 2) Perform your query just like now but also add a .toType(customTypeName) to end of the query.  This will cause the result of the query to be added into your EntityManager with the specified entityType.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The partial entity technique you describe is discussed and presented in John Papa's PluralSight two courses, "[SPA JumpStart](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/single-page-apps-jumpstart)" and "[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 2](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)".

You'll also find relevant code examples in several of the [DocCode Samples Tests](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests); search for the word "partial" among those test files to find what you're looking for.